# How did they film the fight scenes in 'Legend'?

Tags: film-techniques, legend

In *Legend* starring Tom Hardy, he plays both Kray twins, so how exactly did they film the section in the bar where they fight each other? I know some of the framing only has one of their faces in it but from what I remember that there are parts where both faces are in it. I'm assuming CGI but could anyone help?

Comment: On first read, I thought this was about Tom Cruise's movie with the big-horned devil :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used fixed and computer controlled motion cameras to get the exact same filming sequence, and filmed it twice with the actor in different positions.

[One article is here](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/15/movies/how-tom-hardy-plays-his-own-twin-in-legend.html), there are several similar articles around on the net. The fixed camera technique has been used quite a few times. The article denotes one such was done in the original Parent Trap, where they filmed it with an actress and a body double, then refilmed and combined them later in the editing room.